# Is a copy necessary for RX/TX with packet_mmap?

Tags: c++, c, linux, network-programming

I've read over what documentation I could, such as (https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/networking/packet_mmap.txt) and various other blogs, etc.

I'm still unclear on whether or not the RX buffer mapped with the kernel may also be used for TX operations or if I need to copy from the RX buffer to the TX prior to setting send status flags and calling sendto().

From the documentation, the below are statuses:

```
// RX statuses
#define TP_STATUS_KERNEL        0
#define TP_STATUS_USER          1

// TX statuses
#define TP_STATUS_AVAILABLE        0 // Frame is available
#define TP_STATUS_SEND_REQUEST     1 // Frame will be sent on next send()
#define TP_STATUS_SENDING          2 // Frame is currently in transmission
#define TP_STATUS_WRONG_FORMAT     4 // Frame format is not correct
```

The flow appears to be:

1. Packet arrives in RX buffer from kernel with TP_STATUS_USER
2. I have my way with the packet, then set TP_STATUS_SEND_REQUEST
3. The kernel sets TP_STATUS_SENDING, while sending
4. The kernel sets TP_STATUS_AVAILABLE once sending is complete
5. I set TP_STATUS_KERNEL to tell the kernel that I'm done with these packets and they may be overwritten

But, since TP_STATUS_AVAILABLE holds the same value as TP_STATUS_KERNEL, if this flow were correct, the kernel would be clearing out packets as soon as it finishes the TX operation. It just seems to me that a copy to a separate TX buffer may be necessary. There's limited information on using packet_mmap and packet_tx_ring. What examples I've found are mostly for RX (which I have working atm). I would love an example of a RX/TX scenario (bridging raw packets for example).

Does anyone have a better understanding of this? Example bridging would be most helpful as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A note before: I am still reading and learning about `PACKET_MMAP` and the functions in `af_packet.c` so I could be wrong!

I don't think what you are wanting to do is possible natively, I think you'd have to hack the functionality in.

With TPACKET v3 in Rx mode one can receive batches of frames per block. So one issue might be that for Rx you'd need to use TPACKET v2 in order for Tx and Rx to share the same ring (however v3 which only supports Rx is supposed to be faster!).

> I set TP_STATUS_KERNEL to tell the kernel that I'm done with these
>   packets and they may be overwritten

With TPACKET v2 in Tx mode (v3 isn't supported for Tx, only Rx) you write a single frame per block and set the block status to `TP_STATUS_SEND_REQUEST` and call `sendto()`. The Kernel transitions the block status to `TP_STATUS_SENDING` and then `TP_STATUS_AVAILABLE` after transmission is completed.

Another issue might the head of ring pointer. If you receive say 5 frames which are placed into the ring blocks, the ring header is moved along to the 6'th block (the next free space) by the Kernel ready to put any additional frames that may arrive into the next free block. Meanwhile in user-land you pick up those first 5 frames via `poll()` for example, call `do_stuff()` to edit the frames in their blocks directly within the ring, then if you try to call `sendto()` against the same ring, you'd need to move the head of ring pointer back 5 places. Asynchronously if some frames arrive and the head of ring pointer has been moved back, you'll overwrite your modified frames before you've sent them.

As I said, I'm sure you can hack around this stuff but if you have to modify the data you might as well set up two rings. I know that will introduce a copy now between rings which I guess you wanted to avoid though. I have been reading through the `PACKET_MMAP` source code and my understanding is that it should reduce copies but it doesn't seem to do that at all. We can reduce the number of syscalls though by calling `sendto()` for a "bunch" of packets (the ring).

You can read what I have found debugging the Tx path [here](https://github.com/jwbensley/EtherateMT/wiki/EtherateMT-Transmit-Overview) and [here](https://github.com/jwbensley/EtherateMT/wiki/Linux-Kernel-socket()-&-sendto()-References). I'm now about to start tracing through the Rx path. The summary of the information in those links regarding the Tx path though is that after filling your Tx ring with application data (frames) and calling `sendto()` the Kernel copies each packet/frame into an `sk_buff` and the NIC copies the data into it's hardware queue (through DMA) to send the packets/frames on the wire. So that is two copies (although the DMA copy is required!), plus you have to copy your application data into a Tx ring so that makes three copies. This is the same as without `PACKET_MMAP` and `AF_PACKET` except that we initiate the process against batches of frames instead of against each individual frame (so we save some context switches and syscalls).

Once I have traced through the Rx path, next on my list is to compare this again Tx and Rx using `sendmmsg()` and `recvmmsg()`.

Comment: I'm intending to use this method for bridging and altering packets, in place of Pcap (which is incredibly slow on Linux). I noticed as well that TPACKETv3 doesn't support TX. Would it make sense (performance wise) to acquire with v3 (for the single syscall) then copy to another buffet for v2 TX? I'm not sure if the copy is cheaper there than just using a v2 buffet for RX and TX. Thoughts?

Comment: @TrunkFullOfGoats You are in luck, as of today(!) Tx using TPACKET v3 has been added into the latest Kernel version (4.11) see here: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=7f953ab2ba46e8649537942c0a64668ca2ce5cc5 So with that you should be able to use one socket to send and receive without the need to copy the frames between rings (that is what is suggested by the commit comment).

Comment: Perfect! This certainly solves my issue. I suppose the patch details also explain how separate descriptors are necessary for the RX/TX operations in kernels prior to 4.11. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @jwbensley: I am interested in the Rx side of PACKET_MMAP... Did you ever write something up and/or do you happen to have a good reference? Thanks!

Comment: @Nemo I didn't write up the Rx path in the ebd, its not too dissimilar to the Rx but in reverse. Essentially just read the Kernel source, its the source of truth of course on how this all works and once you get into it, it's not that complicated. Packet comes into NIC, is DMA'ed to memory, kernel switches context to get packet and copy into SKB, SKB copied into RX ring, then your userland application can access the packets in the RX ring.

Comment: @jwbensley Thanks; I see now. That is one or two copies more than I was hoping for... My problem is to get a single stream of raw packets from a 10GbE interface into a file without dropping packets and without flow control. This is surprisingly tricky even on modern hardware. Digging into the sources now for AF_PACKET + splice() and AF_XDP...

Comment: @Nemo - Yeah, AF_PACKET is not a zero copy framework. The highest performance method (but least flexible) is to write your own driver, it's not as hard as you might think (assuming you have a "sensible" NIC), here's an example: https://github.com/emmericp/ixy or use an existing framework like DPDK or Snabb.